# Select returning only one row with one column

Tags: joomla-3.x, jdatabase

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('username');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__selected_packages'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('username') . " = ". $db->quote($user->username));
$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadResult();

$row = $db->loadrow();
print_r($row);
```

The output looks something like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => any_username
)
```

It only displays one column, but according to Joomla Docs it should display the whole row somewhat like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => any_username
    [1] => val_of_col1
    [2] => val_of_col2
    [3] => val_of_col3
)
```

*Where am i **wrong with the code**?*

Moreover, [is there any way to display the row data in a HTML table?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/1079/12352)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason being is because you are only selecting the username in your database query. So try changing this:

```
$query->select('username');
```

to this

```
$query->select('*');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it did the job! And what about displaying it as a HTML row?

Comment: Please ask as new question as it's a completely new topic but try something of your own first

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/printing-a-jdatabase-row-as-a-html-table