# How to print a single-row result set as a html table?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jdatabase

I am performing a database query like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__table_name'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('username') . " = ". $db->quote($user->username));
$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadResult();

$row = $db->loadrow();
print_r($row); </pre>
```

The output that I get looks somewhat like this:

> Array ( [0] => any_username [1] => val_of_col1 [2] => val_of_col2 [3] => val_of_col3 )

How to convert it into a **HTML table?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
$rows = $db->loadrow();

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';  
   foreach($rows as $row) {
       // display your results here
   }
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

You first echo out the base table structure and then display your results

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear up a possible misconception about the script in the question...

`$result = $db->loadResult();` does not have an active/necessary role to play in the process.  `$result` is not be used after it is declared and it does not "set up" `loadRow()`.

As for how to echo out each column value, I'll recommend `implode()` as the most concise method.  In doing so, it won't matter if you build your result set from `loadRow()` or `loadAssoc()` because `implode()` will ignore the keys.  What DOES matter is the columns that you write into your SELECT clause -- this will dictate exactly which columns are presented.  It is unlikely that you will want to display ALL of the columns so `*` should be swapped out for literal column declarations (either as a comma separated string or an array of strings).  The snippet to follow will work flawlessly even if you only select a single column (and generate a one dimensional result set).

`$db->loadRow()` with `implode()`:

```
if (!$row = $db->loadRow()) {  // declare and check
    echo "No Row Found";
} else {
    echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' , implode('</td><td>', $row) , '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
}
```

If you would like to display a row of column headings, then use `loadAssoc()` to generate the result set. If you wish to adjust one or more column headings to be printed to screen, use a "column alias" where appropriate in the SELECT clause of your query.

```
if (!$row = $db->loadAssoc()) {  // declare and check
    echo "No Row Found";
} else {
    echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th>' , implode('</th><th>', array_keys($row)) , '</th>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' , implode('</td><td>', $row) , '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
}
```