# How to make a mysqli connection and execute a SELECT query in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, mysql

I am having an issue with a basic query in PHP. The query runs perfectly in PHPMyAdmin, but in the browser I am getting:

> Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in /home/######/public_html/test.php on line 54

I've tried single quotes and double quotes but I'm getting nowhere fast. Below is my full code so far:

```
//display errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

//init Joomla Framework 
define( '_JEXEC', 1 ); 
define( 'JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__).'/' ); // print this out or observe errors to see which directory you should be in (this is two subfolders in) 
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ); 
//echo JPATH_BASE;

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' ); 
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' ); 
require_once ( JPATH_CONFIGURATION   .DS.'configuration.php' ); 
require_once ( JPATH_LIBRARIES .DS.'joomla'.DS.'database'.DS.'database.php' ); 
require_once ( JPATH_LIBRARIES .DS.'import.php' ); 

//DB Connection 
$Config = new JConfig(); 
$db_driver      = $Config->dbtype;   // Database driver name 
$db_host        = $Config->host;     // Database host name 
$db_user        = $Config->user;     // User for database authentication 
$db_pass        = $Config->password; // Password for database authentication 
$db_name        = $Config->db;       // Database name 
$db_prefix      = $Config->dbprefix; // Database prefix (may be empty) 

// Database prefix (if empty then remove prefixing double underscore) 
$db_prefix      = (trim($db_prefix)=="") ? "":$db_prefix; 
//echo $db_prefix;

$db_connect = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass); 

$content_count = 0; 

//CONNECTED! so run a SQL query as per usual 
if (!mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
    $query="SELECT COUNT(*) as ProductSku FROM ".$db_prefix."virtuemart_products";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $query, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {  
        while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){ 
            $content_count = $obj->ProductSku; 
        } 
    }                 
}

//echo $query;  
//echo $content_count;
mysqli_free_result( $db_connect );
```

### Update

Ok, so the code below works fine, but what I want to do is return all records where the `created_on` field has today's date. (rather than the simple query I quoted first, this was just to try and get the code working) Thus the query would be:

```
SELECT product_sku FROM #__virtuemart_products WHERE created_on <= NOW();"
```

Following this I want to export to a csv file, but I am getting an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_fields() on a non-object in

Here is my full code so far:

```
//display errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

//init Joomla Framework 
define('_JEXEC', 1); 
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__).'/');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); 

echo JPATH_BASE;

require_once (JPATH_BASE .DS. 'includes' .DS. 'defines.php'); 
require_once (JPATH_BASE .DS. 'includes' .DS. 'framework.php');

// Start database stuff
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

//Select records that were created today <------This works but i can't get it to //work in the joomla API.
$query = "SELECT product_sku FROM #__virtuemart_products WHERE created_on <= NOW();";

$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();

//print_r($result);

if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$headers = $result->fetch_fields();
foreach($headers as $header) {
    $head[] = $header->name;
}
$fp = fopen('/home/#####/public_html/test1.csv', 'x');
if ($fp && $result) {
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($head)); 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    die;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the Joomla API, therefore you do not need to use `mysqli_` commands.

Instead, use the following:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('COUNT(*)')
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_products'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadResult();

echo $result;
```

As you can see, there's no need for manual database connections, because 
`JFactory::getDbo()` takes care of this for you, by grabbing the connection details from your **configuration.php** file.

The database table prefix `#__` which you can see in the query is Joomla's generic prefix, which will automatically be replaced with the value defined in your **configuration.php**

There are also some `require` statements that you do not need. Have a look at the full code below:

```
<?php

//display errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

//init Joomla Framework 
define('_JEXEC', 1); 
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__).'/');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); 

require_once (JPATH_BASE .DS. 'includes' .DS. 'defines.php'); 
require_once (JPATH_BASE .DS. 'includes' .DS. 'framework.php');

// Start database stuff
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('COUNT(*)')
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_products'));     
$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadResult();

echo $result;
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you, im new to this so i'm on a big learning curve.  I also need to create an array of product_skus, which i want to export to a csv file and email to admin. I have found some code that does this so i'll be looking at that next. Any ideas what is wrong with this? 

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('product_sku')));
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_products')); 
      ->where($db->quoteName (DATE_FORMAT('created_on', '%Y-%m-%d')) = CURDATE();    
$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadResult();

Comment: Let's work in baby steps here and go through your initial for the database query. The code I provided you with....what was the outcome? Did it work, did you get any errors? Let me know. Once solved, you can ask a [new question](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) ;)

Comment: I have just updated the code above.

Comment: I have managed to solve the fetch_fields() issue, i had not used $result = $db->execute();.

Comment: `$db->execute();` is only required for inserting, deleting and updating queries

Comment: ...or if you want to call [getNumRows()](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#Miscellaneous_Result_Set_Methods)  (...but if anyone wants to get the resultset AND count the rows, it seems simpler to just call `count()` on the resultset.)

Answer (score 0):

First, about your first coding attempt:

- You are declaring the vital `$db_name`, but you never use it, and that is likely to be the earliest issue to solve.  That value is best written as the 4th patameter of [mysqli_connect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php).
- `$db_prefix` is a deceptive variable name.  It would be more accurate to call it `$table_prefix` because it is the leading (often randomly generated) portion of the table name string.  It is a member of your `$db_` group of variables, but it cannot, by itself, be used to access a mysql table which may exist in one or more databases on your server.
- As a result of not declaring a database, `if (!mysqli_connect_errno())` would be `true` (because you can actually connect without nominating a database) but `if ($result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $query, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {` would evaluate `false`, so there would not be a result object.  Because `mysqli_free_result( $db_connect );` is outside of your condition block, it is called no matter what, and due to not targetting a database, you are feeding it what it can't eat.

---

That explanation a side, Lodder is right, you should use Joomla's query building methods to make everything simple and reliable.

In your second coding attempt:

- You are using the `getDbo()` method to effortlessly make a database connection.
- You are writing a raw sql query instead of calling the `select()`, `from()`, and `where()` methods.  This isn't necessarily "bad" because there are no variables ergo no vulnerability.  Though as a matter of consistently toeing the Joomla line, it is advisable to use the wrapper methods for all queries.
- Your new SELECT query is only targetting the column `product_sku`, so the appropriate result set generating method is [loadColumn()](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24288/12352)
- When writing your values to your csv file, you don't need to reindex the arrays with `array_values()`, and you should `fclose()` before you `die`. See [an example here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24314/12352).